# R making a list of factors in a dataframe column

Tags: r

Suppose I have a column in a dataframe:

A A A A B B B B B B B B B C C D D E E E E E E E E E F F F F F F F F F

How can I make a list of the factors within that column?
 ie:

A B C D E F

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you mean something like `as.factor(c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C"))`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
levels(factor(df$col))
```

OR:

```
unique(df$col)
```

Or even:

```
names(table(df$col))
```